# XML comments using libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

Hi my requirement is to create a soap based xml file using libxml2,xmltextwriter function. How do I write the first four lines with out the xmltag ?

`POST /InStock HTTP/1.1`

`Host: www.example.org`

`Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8`

`Content-Length: nnn`

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

`<soap:Envelope`

`xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"`

`soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3`

when i use xmlTextWriterWriteFormatComment if always puts the content inside

`<!--  -->`

any help please
Thanks

Comment: `<!-- -->` is XML syntax for comments, so I'm not surprised that something called `xmlTextWriterWriteFormatComment` does this. What makes you think that this is the function you want to use?

Comment: You could try [xmlTextWriterWriteRaw](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterWriteRaw) (I personally haven't tried this).

Answer (score 1):

The first 4 lines are HTTP headers, not XML content.

Comment: yes thats correct .. but My requirement is to create the http headers using libxml2 manually is there any way I can create using libxml function ?

Comment: Hmm...  You might be going about this incorrectly.  lib2xml is a parser library, not a tool for HTTP communication.  I'm not sure what you're using to communicate via HTTP, but I'd be looking there, not in the XML parser.  Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: I just wan to write a text with out xmlcomment <!-- >  using libxml.Is it possible ?